# Implicit differentiation which respect to which variable?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

The height of a cone is 6 inches, and, at it's opening it has a 3 inch diameter. Find a formula for the height as a function of the volume. Compute $h'(V)$

So if the volume, $V$ of a cone is $V = \pi r^2 {h\over 3}$

then my function $h(V)$ can be defined as:    $3v\over \pi r^2$

So now I have $$h(V) = {3v \over \pi r^2}$$

to find $h'(V)$ I'm rewriting the function as $h(V) = 3v * (\pi r^2)^{-1} $

this now requires the product rule, chain rule, and implicit differentiation correct? If so, this is where I'm stuck as I'm uncertain about with respect to which variable I should be doing the implicit differentiation.

Would $$3 *(\pi r^2)^{-1} + 3v*-(\pi r^2)^{-2} * (2 \pi {dr \over dv})$$ be correct?

Comment: what are you differentiating $h(V)$ with respect to? Radius or volume?

Comment: @KennyGuy I think volume

Comment: then $$\frac{dh}{dV}=\frac{3}{\pi r^2}$$ and if radius then $$\frac{dh}{dr}=\frac{-6V}{\pi r^3}$$

Comment: @KennyGuy if it states to find a formula for the height as a function of volume, and then to take the derivate of that formula, does that information tell me which respect to which variable I should be taking the derivative? This is all the information I'm given and I'm not sure if I should be able to tell.

Comment: Hmmmm I am not sure which variable you should take then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you draw the cone as in the diagram, then you can determine a relationship between $h$ and $r$ and use that to eliminate the variable $r$:

[image]

Using similar triangles, we have the relationship:
$$ \frac{r}{1.5} = \frac{h}{6} $$
And so:
$$ r = \frac{h}{4} $$

We already know that $V = \frac{\pi r^2h}{3}$ for a cone, so substituting $r$ from the above equation, we get:
$$ V = \frac{\pi h^3}{48} $$ 
We can now rearrange to get the required relationship:
$$ h = \left( {\frac{48V}{\pi}} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} $$
Now that we have $h(V)$, we can easily differentiate with respect to V to find the result.

PS: Better to rewrite as 
$$ h = \left( {\frac{48}{\pi}} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} V^{\frac{1}{3}} $$
to differentiate easily.